# Code Igniter 3 Join me devuelve el parámetro equivocado

Tags: php, codeigniter, join, codeigniter-3, parametros

estoy creando una aplicación para gestionar partidos de fútbol y competiciones.
Mi aplicación tiene Partidos y estos partidos pertenecen a una Competición en concreto.   Tengo una tabla para partidos, y otra para competiciones, y como de ambas se puede obtener más información a través de vistas, en ambas tablas cuento con el parámetro "slug", el cual me sirve para crear la URL y obtener una vista individual de cada elemento de ambas tablas.
He realizado un join para poder añadir los partidos a una competición en particular, y así todos los partidos pertenecen a una Competición.
Como ambos tienen el párametro **slug**, cuando intento acceder a la vista de un partido en concreto, pasando como parámetro partido['slug'], la función del modelo me devuelve el parámetro competicion['slug'], y no se muy bien como solventar esto para que me devuelva el parámetro que quiero.
Adjunto códigos relevantes al caso:
Este es el código de la función que me devuelve los partidos de la base de datos, dentro del modelo Partido_modelo.php:

```
public function get_partidos($slug = FALSE){
            if($slug === FALSE){
                $this->db->order_by('partidos.id','DESC');
                $this->db->join('competiciones','competiciones.id = partidos.competicion_id');
                $query = $this->db->get('partidos');
                return $query->result_array();
            }
            $query = $this->db->get_where('partidos', array('slug' => $slug));
            return $query->row_array();
        }
```

Esta es la vista de los partidos, la cual me muestra por pantalla la información de todos los partidos, y cuenta con un botón "Saber Más", el cual me lleva a la vista individual del partido, y a cuyo botón le paso el parametro partido['slug']. El problema es que ese parámetro que le llega en realidad es el slug de la tabla competiciones, en lugar del slug de partidos.

```
<h2><?=$titulo?></h2>
<?php foreach($partidos as $partido) :  ?>
    <div class="container">
    <h3><?php echo $partido['titulo']; ?></h3>

    <small><span class="badge badge-primary"><strong><?php echo $partido['nombre']; ?></strong></span></small>
    
    <?php echo word_limiter($partido['body'],60); ?><br>
    
    <small><span style="float:right" class="badge badge-info">Creado el: <?php echo $partido['creacion']; ?></span></small>

    <p><a class="btn btn-warning" href="<?php echo site_url('/partidos/'.$partido['slug']); ?>">Saber más</a></p>
</div>
    <br>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

No creo que lo más eficiente sea cambiar el nombre del parámetro, por lo que me gustaría saber una manera de especificar que el parámetro slug al que me refiero es el de la tabla partidos, y no el de la tabla competición.
Por último no adjunto más código ya que he comprobado que cuando quito la linea del join pasa por parámetro el slug correcto, pero luego de ponerla empiezan los problemas.
Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que poner un alias a uno de los dos "slug":
Antes del order_by(), especifica qué campos quieres extraer tanto de "partidos" como de "competiciones".
En el ejemplo estoy seleccionando todo de "Partidos" (incluyendo slug) y los campos "campo1", "campo2" y "slug" con el alias "slug_competicion" de "competiciones"

```
$this->db->select('partidos.*, competiciones.campo1, competiciones.campo2, competiciones.slug as slug_competicion');
```

luego, podrás referirte al slug del partico con partido['slug'] y al slug de la competicion con partido['slug_competicion'].

=)